# Calculate an edge of a cube

Tags: geometry

The question is:
How far the edge of the cube is increased knowing that if the $2\text{ cm}$ edge of the volume is $2402 \text{ cm}$ ?

I already found that an edge is $(x+2)^3$ but I can't find the equality to calculate the edge.

Can you help me for that ?

Thank you in advance

PS: Sorry if my English is bad but I'm a French student :)

Comment: Uhm, what? I'm sorry but could you rephrase your question? What do you want to compute? What exactly is known?

Comment: i want to calculate the edge of the cube: but the volume is 2402 cm² when we add 2 cm at an edge

Comment: But an edge is certainly not given by $(x+2)^3$. This is in units of $ccm$, while an edge should have $cm$. What exactly is given?

Comment: but if we add 2 cm at a edge and if a edge is x cm, we need to do: (x+2)^3 for calculate the volume. no ?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the question means that increasing the side $x \text{cm}$ of the cube by $2\text{cm}$ increases the volume by $2402 \text{cm}^3$ you need to find the change in volume, which is $(x+2)^3-x^3=2402$.

Expanding this gives you a quadratic and two solutions, one of which is physically possible. You should not need a calculator.

Comment: Ah, well, that result makes way more sense. Impressed that you understood it

Comment: on a corrected I found on the internet, it says: (x + 2)^3=x^3+2402 but I do not understand how they found x^3+2402

Comment: @aera128 The volume of the cube before the increase is $x^3$ and the amount of the increase is $2402$ so the volume of the larger (increased) cube is $x^3+2402$. The side of the larger cube is $2$ bigger than the side of the original cube, so the volume of the larger cube is $(x+2)^3$. These two expressions for the same volume are equal, and give the equation you have to solve.

Comment: ok i'll try with (x+2)^3=x^3+2402

Answer (score 0):

I find:

$$(x+2)^3=x^3+2402$$

$$x^3+6x²+12x+8=x^3+2402$$

$$6x²+12x+8=2402$$

$$6x²+12x-2394=0$$

Divide by $6$:

$$x²+2x-399=0$$

$$-x²-2x+399=0$$

$$\Delta=1600$$

We have $2$ solutions but one is positive:
$19$

Thus an edge length is $19 \text{ cm}$.